# Nginx return 110: (Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream

Tags: java, linux, session, tomcat, nginx

I tried to tweak nginx.conf by adding

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
```

to all locations /

also added:

```
 keepalive_timeout   10;
     proxy_buffering off;
```

and for the ssl:

```
# SSL
ssl                     on;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols           TLSv1 SSLv3;
ssl_ciphers             RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!ADH:+DH; #HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
ssl_session_cache       builtin:10000 shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_timeout     10m;
```

I still get:

```
2014/10/13 18:22:17 [error] 9361#0: *637300 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 30.30.119.123, server: , request: "POST /myserver/... HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9090/myserver/..., host: "43.5.2.3"
```

I also have after the nginx  apache tomcat.

```
configuration on port 9090:

<Connector port="9090"
                           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
                           asyncTimeout="10000000"
                           maxPostSize="0"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
                maxThreads="900"
                acceptAccount="250"
                />
    -->
```

Anything else I should try?
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, tweak the upstreams that take ten minutes to respond.

Comment: How do you tweak the upstreams? could you answer that here please? which params and on which section. and how do you understand that it took 10 mins to respond?

Comment: I don't know anything about your upstream software, so that's for you to figure out. Why did it take the server at port 9090 a proxy_connect_timeout of 600 seconds (10 minutes) to accept the connection. Especially with a localhost connection. Perhaps you are overloading the machine?

Comment: I am having tomcat behind the ngnix. mybe the tomcat doest the problem??